# Using timer to reverse enemy movement in Flash game made with Flixel

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movement, timer, flixel

I am creating a 2d flash game using Flixel 2.5 in Flash Builder. I am trying to reverse enemy movement on an interval so that they will move back and forth over a set space. I felt that a timer would be best for this situation. The enemy class extends FlxSprite. 
I have three class level variables to help with managing the sprite's direction:

```
private var _movementTimer:Timer;
private var _movementTimerEvent:TimerEvent;
private var _forward:Boolean;
public var _directionSet:int = 0;
```

In the constructor, I instantiate the timer like this:

```
//create timer for movement
_movementTimer = new Timer(3000);
//set listener for movement
_movementTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,SetDirection);
//start timer
_movementTimer.start();
//set initial direction
_forward = true;
```

The function called on the timer interval is as follows:

```
/*Reverse direction of this sprite*/
        public function SetDirection():void
        {
            _directionSet++; //increment direction set for debug purposes
            FlxG.log("direction set");
            FlxG.log(_directionSet);

            if(this._forward)
            {
                this._forward = false;
                //set the direction the sprite is facing
                this._facing = RIGHT;
            }
            else
            {
                this._forward = true;
                //set the direction the sprite is facing
                this._facing = LEFT;
            }

        }
```

Then, the update function evaluates the `_forward` flag to determine direction of movement:

```
/*Update this sprite*/
        override public function update():void
        {
            super.update();

            if(this._forward)
            {
                this.acceleration.x = this.maxVelocity.x * .5;
            }
            else
            {
                this.acceleration.x = -this.maxVelocity.x * .5;
            }
        }
```

However, my sprite is not reversing direction, it just continues forward. What am I missing?

EDIT:

I added additional variables and calls to FlxG.log for debugging purposes, and it seems that `SetDirection` is never called, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Add some debug output, and see if SetDirection ever gets called.

Comment: I added some debug code, using a call to FlxG.log in the method:
`_directionSet++; //increment direction set for debug
purposesFlxG.log("direction set");
FlxG.log(_directionSet);`
And it seems that it is never called. But I am not sure why. I assume there is maybe something with how the FlxG game loop is structured.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about Flash or Flixel to help further. It might be worth commenting out all the game code to see if Flixel and Timers are just fundamentally incompatible even if there's nothing else in the app to interfere.

Comment: Your signature for `SetDirection()` is incorrect. It should be `SetDirection(e:TimerEvent):void`. That said, I recall Flash being really forgiving about that so it probably isn't your problem. Are you removing the listener anywhere in your code? Maybe that's happening accidentally?

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 o.m.g. It was the signature for `SetDirection()`. Changing it to `SetDirection(e:TimerEvent):void` as you indicate corrected the issue. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Christian done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature for `SetDirection()` is incorrect. It should be `SetDirection(e:TimerEvent)`. Flash can be forgiving about this sort of thing resulting in some infuriatingly subtle errors.

Answer (score 3):

Using Flash's built in`Timer` isn't a great idea in Flixel. You should really use the `Update` function in conjunction with `FlxG.elapsed`, as this will respect pausing and resuming the game using Flixel.

Here's an overview of how to use Flixel's timing:

http://flashgamedojo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Timer_(Flixel)

Comment: For the record, I took your advice and changed the implementation to a counter using `FlxG.elapsed`, however the previous answer came sooner and corrected the initial issue problem, so I marked his answer correct and gave yours an upvote for helpfulness. Thanks for the advice!